# Png image plane transparency when used as object in hair particle not working with cycles

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I wanted to make a grassland using a brush stroke from Photoshop as the leaves(object) for the a particle hair simulation. Even though, when i render just that image aloe, it keeps its transparency but after rendering the whole particles simulation together, a lot of artifact appear. just in cycles. not in Eeve. Thanks alor

Here is the file and some images

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0k9fcs4irjaq0d6/AADLjPGh233v4E_yuK7o9Kyfa?dl=0

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: could you please pack all the images you're using for the grass and share the file again?